# Should one create a new table for each user on a web app?

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm writing my first web app, and I know enough about databases to know that the schema is important but not enough to know how to actually write a good one.

Is there a standard protocol for handling information stored in each user account?  My instinct is to have one table that stores the user's key and log-in info, and a handle to their table (probably the key?), and then have one table for each user.

But I wonder if there are performance issues around having table for each user or if that seems an incredibly stupid way to do it.  This seems like it should be a "solved problem" since basically all web apps have user accounts, but I haven't been able to find anything via search.  Are there any resources with "solved" schemas for storing various sorts of web data?

Comment: I know this kinda bit old but I was thinking same way for security reason .    e.g to prevent other users reach other tables except theirs .

Comment: @SalemF So yes, there are potential security issues doing it this way, but there are even BIGGER security issues having separate tables.

Simply put, you don't want your web app ever creating tables on the fly. You only want adding or removing of data in the table. Adding and creating tables is a level of permissions higher than adding and deleting rows. And you don't want your web app to have permissions to create or delete tables. This is how you end up having your entire database deleted or copied by a hacker. There are other reasons, but that's the security reason.

Comment: @aranesa  you right it's about permission level , wither way if users can access others raw's he can access others tables . but the idea was keep users on his own table only and provide no permission  to delete or create new tables . either ways of hacker gain controlling to DB he will do what he want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually you would not create a separate table for each user - this solution does not scale well.

Instead you usually put all users' data into a single table (or one table per type of data) and use conditions in the WHERE clause to ensure that a user can only read/write their own data.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your app is something extremely custom, you will want to choose a web-app framework to work with. For the simple things most common frameworks work just about equally well (though there is some rabid disagreement on that). I will assume that you have a programming language where you feel you are the most strong so I would suggest you let that be your primary guide for a web framework. Some common frameworks by language are (this is not even a *close* to an exhaustive list):

- Ruby: [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- Python: [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- Java: [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)

As to your question about the schema, you might want to look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Most frameworks will already have tools to deal with user creation and authentication, but in general you will never want to create a table per user. More common approach is to have a table called users, that had some `id` as a primary key and that is then used as a foreign key that references other data.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah definitely not a good idea. What you should do, is to get familiar with some web application framework because most/all of them provide this for you already. Good choice is for example [Django](http://www.djangoproject.org).

Comment: That kind of takes the learning out of it..... I am here because i can not use Django for the server of my application written entirely in mysql and python and need to figure out good ways to design a database.